# How can redirect to form invalid from the form_valid function in django

Tags: python, django

I am performing some more validation fater the main form has been validated.
I am using class based views

```
def form_valid(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    some custom logic
    if(false)
    Here i want to return to form invalid page with my custom message
```

I am processing the file in form_valid and thats got many steps which i need to check for more validation. so i don't want to move all that logic out to another function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing validation in `form_valid`. Do it in the form, either in `Form.clean` or `Form.clean_FOO`. Refer to the [Django documentation on form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/).

If you insist on mutilating your code-base, then try the following:

```
def form_valid(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    is_actually_valid = some_custom_logic()
    if not is_actually_valid:
        return self.form_invalid(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thats i ok , but is there any way to do what i asked

Comment: @user32 Updated the answer with your request.

Comment: thanks dude , i know u won't be happy but that did the trick. Any way to pass some error message there